# Некорректное отображение в textbox

Tags: c#

отображаются кракозябры при выводе потока(текст русский). Пытался преобразовать в стандартную кодировку для ОС(последние 3 строки) и вывести, одно и тоже. Кто что может сказать?

```
 var cmd1 = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = @"/k """ + cmd + @"""",
                    Verb = "runas",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = cl
                };

                var process = Process.Start(cmd1);
                StreamReader sr1 = process.StandardOutput;

                using (StreamWriter sr = process.StandardInput)
                {
                    if (sr.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sr.WriteLine(@"cl " + outname + @".cpp " + param);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
                        sr.WriteLine(@"exit");
                        buffer = sr1.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                textBox1.Paste(buffer);
                //byte[] ucb = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(buffer);
                //char[] ucc = Encoding.Default.GetChars(ucb);
                //string buffer1 = new string(ucc);
                //textBox1.Paste(buffer1);
```

Comment: Наверняка этот вопрос задавался много раз.
http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread212211.html

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka при изменении на StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput, Encoding.Default) нужен чтобы process.StandardOutput был Stream, а он StreamReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
processStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866 /* Cyrillic (DOS) */);
```